# htaccess rewrite rule - clean up url

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm looking at clearing up urls in my website which is built in PulseCMS.

Currently in blog posts the url includes the word blog, article number, and the title of the article and may look like this for a title of 'This, is a sample - Title'
`https://example.com/blog-10-this,-is-a-sample---title`

I would like to

1. put a '/' between the word blog and the title - make it go 'domain.com\blog\title'
2. remove the blog number - so get rid of '-10', and
3. remove the ',' and the extra '-' from the URL.

So ending up with the following
`https://example.com/blog/this-is-a-sample-title`

My current htaccess rewrite rule is this, and I don't know where to start..

```
RewriteRule ^blog-page-([^-]*)$ ?page=$1&p=blog [L]
RewriteRule ^blog-([^-]*)+? ?d=$1&p=blog [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using this regex to get title : blog-[0-9]+-([a-z,-]+). You need then to sanitize the output (remove , and -).

Comment: `blog-10-this,-is-a-sample---title`.. Very weird to begin with because of the `,` and multiple `-`.

Comment: My advice would be to write some code to fetch all blog posts and clean their names programmatically.

Comment: You cannot remove blog id `10` from blog URL otherwise it cannot load correct blog page internally

Comment: @nice_dev you mean why are the ```,``` and ```-``` in the title?

Comment: @Milos2504 Yes.

Comment: @nice_dev that was just an example. If you look at some of the 'Related' questions on the right hand side on here, some questions have ```,``` in them too, but they are removed in the url.

Comment: @anubhava is it possible to have it /blog/10/title?

Comment: Yes `/blog/10/title` will be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on requirements and follow up comment, you can use these rules:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# redirect from 
# /blog-10-this,-is-a-sample---title
# to /blog/10/this,-is-a-sample---title
# executes repeatedly as long as there are multiple , or -- in URI
RewriteRule ^(blog-\d+)[,-]+(.*?)(?:,|-{2,})(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [N,DPI]

# redirect to clean URL
RewriteRule ^(blog)-(\d+)[,/-]+(.*) /$1/$2/$3 [L,R=302,NE,NC]

# rewrite /blog/10/title
RewriteRule ^blog[/-]([^-]+)/ ?d=$1&p=blog [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^blog-page-([^-]*)$ ?page=$1&p=blog [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, that's fixed the point 3, so it removed the ```,``` and ```-``` but the blog url is still blog-10-title, not blog/10/title

Comment: Try my updated rules in a new browser

Comment: That worked but now it doesn't load the article, as you mentioned in the earlier comments.

Comment: ok I have added a new rule to handle that. Try now.

Comment: That still doesn't load the article. Maybe best if I leave it as blog-10-title?

Comment: Ok so that works, when opening the first blog post for example blog post 10, but then if I click on another one lets say blog post 11, the url goes /blog/10/blog-11-title and it just reloads blog post 10.

when I hover over the links, the links still display the old format, so for example if I go over the link for blog post 10, url is blog-10-this,-is-a-sample---title, but then when I open it it shows as blog/10/title. Is that normal?

Comment: oh that is due to relative URL issue. You can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's fixed it. 
Do you know why the url is still showing as the old url style when I hover over the link?

Comment: Hovering over the link shows URL as you've in your HTML source (before redirect). I suggest you fix HTML at some point.

Comment: Trying to locate the source code now. It's somewhere in the CMS... thanks for you help! much appreciated.

Comment: Does this look like the part where it should be added? ```$title        = $lines[0]; $url_title    = $all_blog_files[$get_id][1].'-'.str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
```

Comment: Yes looks like this is the place

Comment: So I've noticed issues with the htaccess rewrite. If the title doesn't contain a ```-``` then the url rewrite doesn't work. If I add a ```-``` to the title then it renames the title nicely

Comment: If the title is 'Blog title' the url won't be rewritten and would be /blog-11-blog-title, it also won't load the article. If I rename that title to 'Blog - Title' then the url is rewritten to /blog/11/blog-title and it loads the article. So the rewrite seems to only work if a ```-``` is in the title.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment. I've managed to clean up the url in the source, so I got the url to look like this blog-10/title-of-the-article. All cleaned up in the source, however I can't find the blog-10 part, to replace the ```-``` with a ```/```. Can I just do that part through htaccess, and if so how do I need it amended?

Comment: So you want to redirect from `blog-10/title-of-the-article` to `blog/10/title-of-the-article` right?

Comment: Yes, although when I think about it, it's fine the way it is as well.

Comment: Ok got it, I have made a tweak to handle that in my answer